# How to abort robocopy on first error

Tags: windows, shell, mirroring, robocopy

When using robocopy windows utility, what flags do I set so that robocopy aborts on the very first error it sees, similar to xcopy /dry command?

I need to mirror two dirs, and on occasion some files would be locked. I do not want robocopy to continue trying to copy files, or override the files that are not locked - rather the very first error should stop the whole copy process.

**UPDATE:**

I already have the /R set to 0 - unfortunately that it only applies to a single file, NOT to the whole copying process. Hence, the first file is ignored (instead of stopping the copying), but subsequent files are copied.

Comment: robocopy is a windows command that performs file copy operations and extends copy and xcopy functionality. It ships with the windows SDK which is included in several software distributed by Microsoft. I think this is the correct forum.

Answer (score 1):

Use the **Retries** argument and set it to 0:

```
/R:0
```

Robocopy will not retry if an error is found and the command is aborted. What you are experiencing is the fact this option is set by default to 1 thousand, or something similar.

As an added note, you can save the **retries** option to the registry which I believe may be useful in your case. This will save you from having to remember to set it to 0 every time and feels more natural, since you may want to explicitly tell robocopy to retry n times, instead of having to explicitly tell robocopy to not retry.

```
/R:0 /REG
```

Use */REG* when applying */R:* and that setting will be saved to the registry for future use.

---

If you wish to abort the whole robocopy operation, I'm afraid this isn't possible under robocopy. Not to my knowledge at least.

You will in that case want to use [XXCOPY](http://www.xxcopy.com/index.htm#fw_pe) and the **/C0** option.

---

Robocopy philosophy (being a replication tool) stops it from doing this... well, in my view at least until *rollover* is implemented.

Answer (score 0):

We are using an extension to ROBOCOPY called RoboCopyPlus (www.robocopyplus.com). It adds emailo notification and condenses the log files and attaches them to the email.
It adds a whole heap of switches to the standard set of ROBOCOPY switches. Not sure if it woudl do what you're looking for but I'd give it a try.